# Two Custom Options combined: Tier Price doesn't work

Tags: custom-options, tierprice

I'm setting up products and tier prices in Magento, but I've noticed that a in Simple Product with Custom Options (example: blue t-shirt, red t-shirt), the Tier Price won't work if we combine them to reach the quantity.

Tier Prices seem to work only when the quantity is reached from one product variation, but not a combination of two.

I've read several answers on Stack Overflow and the Magento forums, and they recommend to create configurable products.
However this can be pretty hard if a store has lots of products, or lots of variations.

Do you know some workaround to get the Tier Price apply - with a combination of variations?

Comment: can you precise what is the type of blue t-shirt and red t-shirt ? Are they single products with no link between them ?

Comment: They would be Custom Options ("Blue", "Red") of a Simple Product "T-Shirt". On Magento currently, if the Tier Price was, let's say, "10 or more you get a discount", it would work when purchasing 10 Reds or 10 Blues, but not when I'd purchase 5 + 5...

Comment: How can magento know that these two products are linked ?

Comment: Well in my example there's only 1 product (Simple Product), that has two custom options (variations): blue and red. Magento doesn't calculate a tier price when you add up two options of the *same* Simple Product (we are talking about Simple Products here, not Configurable Products). For Configurable Products, there's an extension that allows Tier Price combining (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/spranks-configurabletierprices.html), but again, this is not my case, we have too many options to create a product per option).

Comment: You will need a custom module to achieve this. Or if I was you, I would consider using configurable products with the tier price module you mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that Magento treats products with different custom options as different line items in cart. So, the qty for the two variants of custom options never adds up to be able to qualify the quote item for a particular tier of tiered pricing.

Now, making this work would involve custom work. I can give you pointers as to where you can look to make it work in the code.

Checkout `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal::collect()`

In this method you will need to loop through all the quote items and link the tiered quantity applicable on each of the quote items. So say, you have two variants A and B with quantity 1 and 3. You will loop through the quote items and do something like:

```
$quoteItemA->setTieredQty(1+3);
$quoteItemB->setTieredQty(1+3); //ofcourse 1 and 3 are dynamic here
```

Then in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal::_initItem`

instead of using: `$finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty()); //on line 115 use:`

```
$finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getTieredQty());
```

This involves custom work but the approach I'm listing should work with some on the fly adjustments as you work through it.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm, this works

```
        /* hard coded - start */ 
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $total_qty = 0;
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item2) {
          if ($item2->getProductId() == $quoteItem->getProductId()) $total_qty+= $item2->getQty();    
        }
        $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($total_qty);
        // $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty());
        /* hard coded - end */
```